# Move element when :active

Tags: javascript, html, css

I created form for buttons in CSS and one of features is that when user clicks button it is being moved 2 pixels down and right to give an effect of clicking.

But, the problem is that I have to specify position for every button and additionally for `:active` selector what makes it inconvenient (It is easy to forget to change position for `active` selector).

Is there any way to specify movement in my Button Form?

Button Form:

```
    .userPanel .button{
    ...
    /* button features */
    ...
    }

    .userPanel .button:active{
    ...
    }
```

Examples of buttons:
Button1:

```
.userPanel #logOutButton{
...
top: 100px;
left: 120px;
...
}
.userPanel #logOutButton:active{
top: 102px;
left: 122px;
}
```

Button2:

```
.userPanel #buyButton{
...
top: 40px;
left: 60px;
...
}
.userPanel #buyButton:active{
top: 42px;
left: 62px;
}
```

(`#logOutButton` and `#buyButton` are `divs` with `class="button"`.)

I was thinking about writing something in a form that would solve it for every button.
Button Form:

```
    .userPanel .button{
    ...
    /* button features */
    ...
    }

    .userPanel .button:active{
    top: top + 2px;
    left: left + 2px;
    }
```

But, of course it does not work.
Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `transform: translate(2px, 2px);`.
This solution could be more universal than using margins, because you do not need to redefine margins for different button elements on your page. 
But it can't be used with the old browsers.

Comment: Just the job! That's what I meant, no I do not have to specify position twice!

Answer (score 3):

Using margin should work. You could add `2px` to the left and `2px` on top. Something like this:

```
.userPanel .button:active {
    margin-top: 2px;
    margin-left: 2px;
}
```

Comment: Margins work well, but then we are limited to use left and top to specify position, because we cannot use right,bottom,margin-left, margin-right.

Answer (score 1):

Try use the "margin-top" and "margin-left" rules. Like so:

```
.button1:active {
margin-left:5px;
margin-top:5px;
```

}

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/50dqhrps/

Is this what you meant?